# Can I use sqlite over http?

Tags: python, http, sqlite, filesystems

To open an SQLite database, one needs to specify a file name.  The database I want to use is hosted on some webserver.  Obvious solution: download it!  But the thing is several gigs, and SQLite has this nifty VFS feature, so perhaps it can be made to work?  (I want read-only access, otherwise its probably hopeless.)

Possibly relevant: I'm using Python, but if the solution depends on something that is only exposed at the level of C, that's okay.

Comment: would making a HTTP REST interface for SQL commands solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it could be made to work, but you'd have to write the VFS yourself, and Python's built-in SQLite driver does not support VFSes.

Comment: you could use the HTTP REST instead of sqlite api, that was my suggestion

Comment: It would not solve my problem, since I do not control the server where the file is hosted.  I have basically no relationship with the people who do control it, aside from the fact that they told me "if you want this file, you can download at this url".  I've already downloaded it by the way, the question is of mostly theoretical interest.  CL's answer told me pretty much what I expected to hear.

Comment: you could implement a FUSE layer so sqlite would see the db as a file, although random access over HTTP would be very inefficent.

Comment: Neat idea.  But I'm on windows.  Though there is this thing I guess: https://dokan-dev.github.io/

Comment: better edit the question and add follwing information 1. that you are limited to windows and 2. you are forced to use only read only http access to sqlite database. maybe use a linux VM. in these cases windows is only an obstruction to solving any problem.

Comment: I suppose I could use the new-fangled Linux subsystem that Windows 10 has, but the work of implementing a FUSE file system sounds a bit daunting.

Comment: i personally think that writing a FUSE layer is easier than writing an sqlite VFS driver

Comment: I believe you.  But it still sounds pretty hard.